# Large Docker images get stuck towards the end of downloading

Tags: networking, debian, docker, linux-networking, debian-bullseye

Whenever I pull medium-to-large Docker images onto my server, they download almost all the way, but then they get stuck for multiple minutes before eventually finishing. I've looked in the Docker daemon debug logs, but they only indicate that the image is being downloaded, with no errors or warnings of any kind. I don't think it's a rate limiting issue, as it happens both on the Docker Hub and ghcr.io, and I don't think it's a network issue, as I can pull images on my MacBook connected to the same network without issue. I've already tried a fresh install of Debian, but the issue persists.

The issue only seems to affect images (and layers of images) that are beyond a certain size, but I don't yet know what that size is.

**Images that work:**

- `alpine`
- `busybox`
- `memcached`
- `hello-world`

**Images that do not work:**

- `jellyfin/jellyfin`
- `pihole/pihole`
- `python`

The machine in question is an old Lenovo desktop on my home network with an Intel Xeon E31230, 8GB of RAM, and a gigabit Intel 82579LM ethernet controller. It's running Debian 11, Docker Engine 20.10.21, containerd 1.16.12, runc 1.1.4, and docker-init 0.19.0.

I have also recorded [a video](https://youtu.be/V1WFII9hQAA) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be my router. It must be some weird difference between how it treats wireless devices and ethernet devices, but plugging the machine into the base router (instead of the mesh WiFi system) solved the problem.